# Example of a family of Boolean subalgebras such that their union is not a Boolean algebra

Tags: logic, set-theory, boolean-algebra

I read that given a family of Boolean subalgebras, their union is not in general a Boolean algebra except if the family is directed. What is an example of a family of Boolean subalgebras whose union is not a Boolean algebra?

Comment: The union of the Boolean algebras $\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ and $\{\varnothing,\{2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ has six elements and is not a Boolean algebra.

Comment: That "except if the family is directed" is not quite right. If $B$ is a Boolean algebra with more than $4$ elements, then the family of all $4$-element subalgebras of $B$ is not directed but its union is a Boolean algebra, namely $B$.

Comment: @user14111 Next time please also pay attention to titles when making edits :)